# Change style on hover while a key is held down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've set up a style to turn a single-cell table, for example:

```
<TABLE ONCLICK='goSomewhere("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes", "http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no")' CLASS="mybutton">
    <TR>
        <TD>This is a button</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Into a button via CSS such as:

```
table.mybutton {
    border : 1px solid;
    border-radius : 8px;
    border-spacing : 2px;
    font-size : 80%;
    display : inline-table;
    cursor : pointer;
}
table.mybutton:hover {
    background-color : black;
    color : white;
}
```

I've managed to get it to visit one of two URLs depending on whether the Shift key is held down via this Javascript:

```
var shift = false;

function shiftHandler(event) {
    shift = event.shiftKey;
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", shiftHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("keypress", shiftHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", shiftHandler, false);

function goSomewhere(url1, url2) {
    if (shift) {
        window.location.href = url2;
    } else {
        window.location.href = url1;
    }
}

function goSomewhereElse(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The last piece is that I'd like the background color of the button while hovering to change depending on whether the Shift key is held as well. Can this be done? Can it be done without extra libraries?

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s_jsfiddle/sd6tqd3t/8/)

Comment: You have a good reason for not using an actual button in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe Does that have a bearing on how difficult this is to solve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do it by changing an element's class when the key is pressed or released. Adding a line to your code:

```
function shiftHandler(event) {
    shift = event.shiftKey;
    document.body.className = shift ? 'shift-pressed' : '';
};
```

Then you can select that class in your CSS:

```
.shift-pressed table.mybutton:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I like this, and it works... once I've clicked somewhere on the page. Until I do, though, it doesn't seem to take. Any ideas? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s_jsfiddle/sd6tqd3t/9/) (Firefox 35.0.1)

Comment: Nevermind, that might just be an oddity of JSFiddle. Works fine on a real page. Thanks!

Comment: You don't get any key events without keyboard focus, which is automatic on a full page but not the iframes used by JSFiddle.

Comment: I made my own minimalist fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1vbvwaxb/1/. It can read the shift key without focus, but only when the pointer moves. (Thanks for the idea, blacksquare!)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Use a 'mouseover' event attached to the button.

```
var element = document.getElementById("#button-id");
element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    if (shift) {
         //make the color change here
    }
})
```

Comment: Noobish question, but as the event listener is attached to the specific ID'ed element, do I still have to getElemenentByID again in the loop to make the style change?

Comment: You can pull the element from the event object , or Use the original element variable.